# How to change view Pager Tab in Android from child fragment of any Tab?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have 3 Tab name fragment 1,fragment 2,fragment 3.fragment 1 has one button upon clicking that another fragment like fragment 1_2 will open in same tab and fragment 1_2 has one button upon clicking that fragment 2 will open and the tab should change,But i am not able to change the Tab.

Comment: post some code of the activity having three fragment and fragment 1 code also...posting code can help the stackoverflow community to have better insight about the problem and what have you tried till now.

Comment: Use event bus and you don't need to worry about child and parent fragmets

Answer (score 0):

You can place this snippet in click button

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).select();
```